# laravel5.1 validate number

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

How to validate numbers using laravel validator. In my case I need to validate if a number is between "1.00" and "50.00".

As seperator between the number pairs the "." and the "," should be allowed. The number should have only two decimal places. Is there a way to get this done using standart laravel validators combined?

using a regex, the regex should match these requirements:

starting with 0-9 (2 numbers are possible)

followed by one . or one ,

followed with 0-9 (2 numbers are possible)

OR simple numbers like 1-9 with NO dots and NO commas

numbers between 1 and 50 should be allowed in total.
This regex should be used for a prepaid system where users should be able to topup
their accounts from 1 to 50. For this reason entries like 1.00 and 1,00 should be valid as well as 1 or 2.
50.00 is the maximum of amount. 1.00 the minimum.

Comment: Hmm I'm not that good in RegEx, could you show me a regEx for this, so I can learn maybe something from it? Using the regex is documented well I think.

Comment: In hindsight (and after doing some research into RegEx), I may have to retract my comment. It's simple enough to do regex for same length decimal values (such as `10.00 to 50.00`), but when it comes to variable length (`1.00 to 50.00`) RegEx doesn't seem able to handle it. Also, I don't think you'll need to test for `,` as your range doesn't allow separators, unless you're intending to use `,` as your decimal place marker. I'll see if I can think of another solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited first post, so you can point out the requirements better I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you are lookig for:

```
/^((([1-4][0-9]|[1-9])([,.]\d{1,2})?)|(?:50([,.]0{1,2})?))$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expresions like this:

```
   $rules = [
       'field' => 'regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/'
   ];
```

PS: This tool could be useful https://regex101.com/

Comment: You missed the key point of the question: *[...] between "1.00" and "50.00"*. This doesn't work for that condition. 0.99 and 50.01 both pass...

Comment: Is there a way to use regex for this or impossible?

Comment: With regex always there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the following Request class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class TestRequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'number' => [
                'required',
                'regex:/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
                'numeric',
                'min:1',
                'max:50'
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function all() {
        $data = parent::all();
        if (isset($data['number'])) {
            $data['number'] = str_replace(',','.', $data['number']);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

and in Controller inject this Request class:

```
public function test(TestRequest $request)
{
      dd($request->all());    
}
```

Comment: any way to redirect user with an error message like I used to do with validators?